# Postgres Materialized view refresh failure

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-12

I want to know if materialized view in Postgres would hold the current data(last refreshed data) in case the 'materialized view refresh' fails for some reason?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW` respects transactional guarantees just like other SQL statements. So yes, if the statement fails, the materialized view will be unchanged.